# Convergence in the product topology for B([0,1])

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

Let $I = [0, 1]$ with its usual topology and let $B(I)$ be the set of all functions $f : I \rightarrow I$. Furthermore, for all $i \in I$ let $X_i = I$ and $X = \Pi_i X_i$ with the product topology. We can identify $X$ with $B(I)$ and therefore endow $B(I)$ with the product topology. Now let $C(I)$ be the set of all continuous functions from $I$ to $I$ and $F(I)$ be the set of all functions with finite support.

Show that if $f \in C(I)$ and $f(i) \neq 0$ for some $i$ then there is no sequence of functions in $F(I)$ that converges to $f$ for the product topology.

I am having some trouble proving this, it makes sense intuitively since $f$ itself does not have finite support but it seems to me that for any basis set of the product topology that contains $f$ will also contain an element of $F(I)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed true that any basic set of the product topology contains a member of $F(I)$. So $F(I)$ is dense in $B(I)$. So you'd expect (in a metric space, e.g.) there to be a sequence from $F(I)$ converging to any point of $B(I)$ and this exercise shows that this is not the case.

If $f_n$ is a sequence of functions from $F(I)$ converging to some $f \in B(I)$, so the support of $f_n$ (i.e. $S_n:=\{x \in I: f_n(x) \neq 0\}$) is finite and let $S=\bigcup_n S_n$, which is an at most countable set. The fact that we use the product topology on $B(I)$ implies that $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n$ and $x \notin S$ and so $f(x)=0$ for all $x \notin S$, i.e. $f$ has at most countable support. This uses that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x$ (product topology is pointwise convergence, or projections are continuous).

Now note that any *continuous* $f: I \to I$ with $f(p) \neq 0$ for some $p \in I$, has uncountable support so cannot be a limit of a sequence from $F(I)$.

Comment: As an aside: the subspace of functions with at most countable support (also called the $\Sigma$-product) is a nice example of a sequentially compact space that is not compact (it's dense in $B(I)$).

Comment: Ahh ok I was having trouble showing that convergence in product topology implies pointwise convergence but I see why that is now. The point is that even though a set in the base for the product topology only has finitely many product factors that aren't the whole set $I,$ topological convergence is a property that needs to be shown for ANY open set contiaing $f.$ So it does imply pointwise convergence. Thanks!